# C# LINQ Join com condição OR?

Tags: c#, sql, banco-de-dados, linq, expressões-lambda

Estou precisando de escrever esse `SQL` em `Linq`, porém na condição desse `JOIN` é o que me pega.

```
SELECT * FROM
Boleto_Retorno AS BR 
LEFT JOIN Recebimentos AS R ON SUBSTRING(BR.CH_NossoNumero,1,11) = 
CASE WHEN LEN(BR.CH_NossoNumero) = 12 
THEN SUBSTRING(R.CH_NossoNumero,1,11) 
ELSE NULL END
OR BR.CH_NossoNumero = 
CASE WHEN LEN(BR.CH_NossoNumero) > 12 
THEN R.CH_NossoNumero 
ELSE NULL END
LEFT JOIN Clientes AS C ON C.CD_Cliente = R.CD_CodigoCliente

WHERE (BR.VF_Processado = 'true') 
AND (BR.DT_DataRecebimento BETWEEN @DataInicial AND @DataFinal)
```

Já tentei fazer assim

```
from Boleto_Retorno in db.Boleto_Retorno.AsNoTracking()
    where Boleto_Retorno.VF_Processado == true
    && Boleto_Retorno.DT_DataRecebimento >= dataInicial
    && Boleto_Retorno.DT_DataRecebimento <= dataFinal
from Recebimentos in db.Recebimentos
where Boleto_Retorno.CH_NossoNumero.Substring(1, 11) == 
    (
        Boleto_Retorno.CH_NossoNumero.Length == 12 ? Recebimentos.CH_NossoNumero.Substring(1, 11) : null) 
        || Boleto_Retorno.CH_NossoNumero == (Boleto_Retorno.CH_NossoNumero.Length > 12 ? Recebimentos.CH_NossoNumero : null
    )

select new ModelBoletoRetorno{ //campos da tabela}).ToList();
```

mas não retornar igual a instrução `SQL` o retorna umas 9 linhas e a expressão `Linq` retorna umas 420.000 linhas.

***Observação:*** *ignorem o* `select *`

Comment: Essa SQL não é traduzido corretamente para Linq, o ideal, faça uma `View` e chame pela camada de persistência.

Comment: esse segundo `WHERE` que você adicionou deveria ser na verdade um `ON`, porém, não sei se será possível montar essa expressão, então sugiro que você crie uma `procedure` no banco que execute a consulta original em SQL à partir de um filtro de data de recebimento que você informará. A ideia da `View` sugerida acima também é uma boa opção, porém, como vejo que existe filtro na consulta (principalmente de data), talvez a procedure seja mais performática.

Comment: esse sql já é uma procedure, e estamos tirando elas e "convertendo" em linq. Eu montei de outro jeito, um foreach da lista do Boleto_Retorno, e um metodo que faz uma busca (firstOrDefault) no recebimentos com as condições feitas da procedure. Embora tive que ser obrigado a ir por esse caminho ja que nao é possivel via linq. Mas deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

Falta o join

Nesse caso a estrutura deveria ficar próxima a isso

```
var query = (from ta in ctx.TableA
             join tb in ctx.TableB
               on ta.Id equals tb.Id into TJoin
             from Tables tbs in TJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where tbs.Id != 2
             select new TablesJoinViewMode
             {
                 Id1 = ta.ID,
                 Id2 - tb.Id
                 /* set other properties*/
             });
```